# Eclipse to Android Studio - Gradle Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, gradle

I receive errors when trying to import my Cordova based, eclipse exported "build.gradle" file, when importing into Android Studio:

"Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.9"

However, upon changing the version using a local gradle distribution I receive the following:

"You are using an old, unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.8 or greater."

Anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same issue, you should check this link where everything is pretty well explained:

http://rexstjohn.com/exporting-android-project-eclipse-android-studio-0-4-0/